# Safari treats .htaccess different than other browsers

Tags: .htaccess

I have links like these:

```
www.domain.com/page.php?id=1#info
```

I'd just like to hide the .php to get this:

```
www.domain.com/page?id=1#info
```

For this reason I found this .htaccess script:

RewriteEngine on

```
# to make `/path/index.php` to /path/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*/)index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

This does exactly the job and works in all browser except safari, which will output:

```
www.domain.com/page?id=1
```

The #info is gone.

How could a browser interpret a .htaccess different? Can someone help me to write the correct .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari behaves the way every browser should:

> Fragments depend on the document MIME type and are **evaluated by the
>   client** (Web browser). Clients are **not supposed to send** URI-fragments
>   to servers when they retrieve a document, and without help from a
>   local application (see below) fragments do not participate in HTTP
>   redirections.
>
> [Wikipedia: Fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Basics)

In plain English: the part of the URL after the `#` shouldn't be sent to the server by the browser. The browser should handle this locally. This means that you might loose the fragment when you apply redirects (rewrite rules).

Comment: Ok, this is very interesting, thank you! But what would be the correct way to handle the rewrite without loosing the identifier?

Comment: I guess I could use a rule, that would interpret links without php as files with php endings but therefore I would have rename all links in my page, which I don't think is the right way. Or is it?

Comment: You should link to the URL you want to be visible in your browser. So don't link to `www.domain.com/page.php?id=1#info` in your HTML, but link to `www.domain.com/page?id=1#info` directly. Mod_rewrite is not meant to change this afterwards (as you're doing right now). If there are still links to the old URL (with the `.php` in it) on the internet, you should choose if you redirect them (while losing the fragment) or just accept it.

Comment: Ok, perfect! As I already accepted your answer this was really enlightening. Thank you for your quick support.